# Adding spaces with InfoPath

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules

Is there a way to convert strings to string like this.

'ABCD1234' -> 'ABCD 1234'

'ABC1234' -> 'ABC 1234'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Rule to accomplish what you need using Michael Kay's *Double Translate Method*.

- For your field add a Rule of type **Action**.
- Use the **Set a field's value** action
- Use the current field `.` as the Field
- For the value use the following formula:

  - `concat(translate(., translate(., "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", ""), ""), " ", translate(., translate(., "0123456789", ""), ""))`